Is it a problem if a learner asks/answers wholly in broken Chinese?
There was this post Asking questions completely in Chinese (~8 years ago), where there was a conclusion that asking and answering questions in Chinese is fine.  It was subsequently affirmed Your input: Do we allow questions and answers written completely in Chinese? (~6 years ago) and To suggest that Chinese SE questions be written solely in English (~3 years ago).  (And also Can I Answer Questions by Chinese ~6 years ago.)
However, I feel there's a hidden assumption in all of these posts that the authors' Chinese levels are unproblematic.  But what if instead, the author is not a native Chinese speaker, and their Chinese is buggy.
Question: Is it a problem if a learner asks/answers wholly in broken Chinese?
For example, I think I could manage to write questions in Chinese, but they would be far from perfect.

Another user asked a similar question here: Is asking for correction on questions written in Chinese on the comment considered too much?.
